# How to sign emails to setup DKIM and DMARC

Tags: emails, advertising

After setting up my Drupal 8 site in the server, I noticed that none of the emails go to the inbox in Gmail and it all gets stored in Spam. Upon further investigation I found that this is because the emails are being sent via the PHP Mailer and its not being signed and authenticated.

I'm not that familiar with Drupal programming, therefore any suggestions and instructions on how I can get this configured via code/modules etc would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: DMARC is part of your DNS configuration, Drupal does not affect that. DKIM is part of your mailserver configuration, Drupal cannot affect that either. What you can do is make sure that all Drupal's mails are send/redirected via a properly configured mailserver by using one of the modules below.

Answer (score 3):

Please check out the following two modules to have your Drupal mails send by a mailserver. Apart from that it may already be sufficient to just set a SPF record for your domain as DKIM and DMARC has actually nothing to do with Drupal.

---

#### PHPMailer

https://www.drupal.org/project/phpmailer

> Adds SMTP support for sending e-mails using the PHPMailer library.
>   Comes with detailed configuration instructions for how to use Google
>   Mail as mail server.

#### SMTP Authentication Support

https://www.drupal.org/project/smtp

> This module allows Drupal to bypass the PHP mail() function and send
>   email directly to an SMTP server. The module supports SMTP
>   authentication and can even connect to servers using SSL if supported
>   by PHP.

---

#### How To use an SPF Record to Prevent Spoofing & Improve E-mail Reliability

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-an-spf-record-to-prevent-spoofing-improve-e-mail-reliability

> A carefully tailored SPF record will reduce the likelihood of your
>   domain name getting fraudulently spoofed and keep your messages from
>   getting flagged as spam before they reach your recipients.