# The email doesn't have the DKIM signature it would get from mail()

Tags: 7, webforms, emails

My web host (HostGator shared server) normally signs outbound emails with DKIM. When I send emails from Drupal 7.69 (and Webform 7.x-4.22 for compatibility with CiviCRM), however, there's no DKIM. Thoughts?

drupal_email_test is a simple webform node that sends an email.

> [image: Drupal snippet]

host_email_test.php is PHP script that calls `mail()` and `phpinfo()`.

> [image: screenshot]

The email from drupal_email_test doesn't have a DKIM section.

```
Delivered-To: wjcaway@gmail.com
Received: by 2002:ac8:82c:0:0:0:0:0 with SMTP id u41csp1168755qth;
        Wed, 25 Mar 2020 16:51:26 -0700 (PDT)
X-Google-Smtp-Source: ADFU+vvnBvwzKRbgGvFqhHvys6G5bkmSPqrZQ7yL/hKlukMe0LLzAttQHbqXILe4pidK7bzYhSPv
X-Received: by 2002:a50:baef:: with SMTP id x102mr5586983ede.238.1585180286135;
        Wed, 25 Mar 2020 16:51:26 -0700 (PDT)
ARC-Seal: i=1; a=rsa-sha256; t=1585180286; cv=none;
        d=google.com; s=arc-20160816;
        b=tVYoRjo8M4yalE1lA5boYt8xwbpprqjfxgOMns2QsGK07XA6/TF7XmJOoS3inP3EuB
         PMbKfKebyTyPWPwpV07Imz/vQaeVjvE1lsuFvVhBS7mudD7gGINm6FiOB3LP3n1beSFJ
         qOksOAgoeEddRt5k9o3KwzQkaKAWqW2gKQFfd/y4EMEyCMplz+yeA+BQ4Q3gZHpHUyQy
         A8NqHojzHQBzKEYlikLahS+5G9SKsfnYI47/CoTcEZ6gRGL+maenhz+tDNPe05vi4wes
         lqjEr2mYdw/UIbXd19iRg+XaAxWQgZgPexfImUuR534FrDY+kPoYHNNtsz6p0wZRi9qs
         OZ5Q==
ARC-Message-Signature: i=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/relaxed; d=google.com; s=arc-20160816;
        h=date:message-id:reply-to:from:content-transfer-encoding
         :mime-version:subject:to;
        bh=5urliemGVkGxGHJiDO8WhZkb/ihL1brX33ZfPAwo4z4=;
        b=RH8M7dQczy8TaRLjAg+SVI/RURig/J1qXvhUxvMqeaabpqS7bIqzzhAawGzQq0YAYk
         wlXXLqjRKHngAYYSCPj8A1r1PfqEYdlE3ukfpJ7KuQpdj+y2B8NDCc6l3J3uuxAtLgAJ
         OhNNZhmaU+xPihJFlSa4ihW0kRmCPU86Qc2oev44Qy++3Yfyg5AOj5xonfSBNhfNy5wu
         r4BVr813Oye6DEL3Ax1TWcn6j32/LDO0y2TwEa50ymaqec404ywz3Sv16WtxOvbuxzP7
         4y0ZWw8wHltD3kU8CAlIQ2PU9mmjXuJGpIgpVdMutgurQ1ksw8ES21ovvCE+lpRA0wm2
         snsg==
ARC-Authentication-Results: i=1; mx.google.com;
       spf=pass (google.com: domain of it@unidosnow.org designates 192.185.50.73 as permitted sender) smtp.mailfrom=it@unidosnow.org
Return-Path: <it@unidosnow.org>
Received: from gateway24.websitewelcome.com (gateway24.websitewelcome.com. [192.185.50.73])
        by mx.google.com with ESMTPS id e27si310612edc.194.2020.03.25.16.51.25
        for <wjcaway@gmail.com>
        (version=TLS1_2 cipher=ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256 bits=128/128);
        Wed, 25 Mar 2020 16:51:26 -0700 (PDT)
Received-SPF: pass (google.com: domain of it@unidosnow.org designates 192.185.50.73 as permitted sender) client-ip=192.185.50.73;
Authentication-Results: mx.google.com;
       spf=pass (google.com: domain of it@unidosnow.org designates 192.185.50.73 as permitted sender) smtp.mailfrom=it@unidosnow.org
Received: from cm11.websitewelcome.com (cm11.websitewelcome.com [100.42.49.5])
    by gateway24.websitewelcome.com (Postfix) with ESMTP id DD81447A8C
    for <wjcaway@gmail.com>; Wed, 25 Mar 2020 18:51:24 -0500 (CDT)
Received: from cloud150.hostgator.com ([108.167.158.90])
    by cmsmtp with SMTP
    id HFnwjVvjpSl8qHFnwj3Eri; Wed, 25 Mar 2020 18:51:24 -0500
X-Authority-Reason: ss=1
Received: from y2dg1g3q by cloud150.hostgator.com with local (Exim 4.92)
    (envelope-from <it@unidosnow.org>)
    id 1jHFnw-000R1R-OG
    for wjcaway@gmail.com; Wed, 25 Mar 2020 18:51:24 -0500
To: wjcaway@gmail.com
Subject: Form submission from: email test
X-PHP-Script:  for 
X-PHP-Originating-Script: 648:system.mail.inc
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8; format=flowed; delsp=yes
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8Bit
X-Mailer: Drupal Webform
From: "Hallo via UnidosNow" <info@unidosnow.org>
Reply-To: "Hallo" <info@unidosnow.org>
Message-Id: <E1jHFnw-000R1R-OG@cloud150.hostgator.com>
Date: Wed, 25 Mar 2020 18:51:24 -0500
X-AntiAbuse: This header was added to track abuse, please include it with any abuse report
X-AntiAbuse: Primary Hostname - cloud150.hostgator.com
X-AntiAbuse: Original Domain - gmail.com
X-AntiAbuse: Originator/Caller UID/GID - [648 501] / [47 12]
X-AntiAbuse: Sender Address Domain - unidosnow.org
X-BWhitelist: no
X-Source-IP: 
X-Source-L: No
X-Exim-ID: 1jHFnw-000R1R-OG
X-Source: 
X-Source-Args: 
X-Source-Dir: unidosnow.co:/cc-unidosnow-co
X-Source-Sender: 
X-Source-Auth: y2dg1g3q
X-Email-Count: 9
X-Source-Cap: eTJkZzFnM3E7eTJkZzFnM3E7Y2xvdWQxNTAuaG9zdGdhdG9yLmNvbQ==
X-Local-Domain: no

Submitted on Wednesday, March 25, 2020 - 19:51
Submitted by user: Anonymous
Submitted values are:

email from: info@unidosnow.org
email to: wjcaway@gmail.com
email line: Line from Drupal - test from Drupal Webform
```

The email from host_email_test.php contains the DKIM signature.

```
Delivered-To: wjcaway@gmail.com
Received: by 2002:ac8:82c:0:0:0:0:0 with SMTP id u41csp1164145qth;
        Wed, 25 Mar 2020 16:45:10 -0700 (PDT)
X-Google-Smtp-Source: ADFU+vudAdnQKbLNwwcVPJnEA9xaqcvZnn6JsNAQgwj7AteKAgYcaG/7Z3fPiHUSrqHsTXiNlrUo
X-Received: by 2002:a17:907:11cc:: with SMTP id va12mr5334563ejb.225.1585179910035;
        Wed, 25 Mar 2020 16:45:10 -0700 (PDT)
ARC-Seal: i=1; a=rsa-sha256; t=1585179910; cv=none;
        d=google.com; s=arc-20160816;
        b=PWe68maxwiuMNl6acYdK6ftBihsoDxvajKxfwVds93nyCGLZQ1Hj2Y4hFxv2pDzfdK
         pqypMhaJqbos5JeizBnXip8NTG5nhnmyGx0P6jMfLM6GlR1a2nt9cz7+KP46Ze8it4wq
         EXxR2EOHYqOpVoXpU2HuyPxKZbn0++wi7xxw82aTWKzxDq5CDMlfRPb6UKMvuteXVr59
         W26r6+WLE0+Yk21/EmZv984joRJFiWTZa6kG70WIdKoWT3ZmKAhlVqO68x5EKQvR3PIM
         /bqaegmW1m0xFL4C/M+FUUhqwGoY74EAlihyg2bUeftU8ICOKSyRWsetRTPN/MXmJWg0
         vB1Q==
ARC-Message-Signature: i=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/relaxed; d=google.com; s=arc-20160816;
        h=date:message-id:from:subject:to:dkim-signature;
        bh=M0VMoOovcbMGQ4upi/77pqMguHM5hO8iG91ARyXv/ho=;
        b=m73KZDNfwBtEzbHd2EtvVfw9D/VMOkbOArQ8m9/R172PJCE0TmQcaGMKwAreZA1PeH
         O9gOy2I6M1LW0a6ZrBeucDP8QjtoT+JNuhOj1rsnbevXwqJk2YXBmBjtyTJr5tndiBte
         FIp2MKuZ5nLtJvamvi7aPBAyXWm/795WauFCYfM61Ihh4ATQINvWVUHb9rb4eiQnxFLC
         PuywZ1ck31o603lpkSvfjW7xIbTXl0Zm4bEE3PZRSpyg1Hn6i2iyvLbGRMfnH7j6bR+f
         aAWpVBx2FXu63h6Bhpt8p8KdDVMV04LNlet1C8rlsugsVauzaj1lY9VF7I2Jy2upVP9A
         TKSw==
ARC-Authentication-Results: i=1; mx.google.com;
       dkim=pass header.i=@unidosnow.co header.s=default header.b=A8IkBXOE;
       spf=pass (google.com: domain of y2dg1g3q@cloud150.hostgator.com designates 192.185.145.170 as permitted sender) smtp.mailfrom=y2dg1g3q@cloud150.hostgator.com
Return-Path: <y2dg1g3q@cloud150.hostgator.com>
Received: from gateway32.websitewelcome.com (gateway32.websitewelcome.com. [192.185.145.170])
        by mx.google.com with ESMTPS id t4si278257edy.487.2020.03.25.16.45.09
        for <wjcaway@gmail.com>
        (version=TLS1_2 cipher=ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256 bits=128/128);
        Wed, 25 Mar 2020 16:45:10 -0700 (PDT)
Received-SPF: pass (google.com: domain of y2dg1g3q@cloud150.hostgator.com designates 192.185.145.170 as permitted sender) client-ip=192.185.145.170;
Authentication-Results: mx.google.com;
       dkim=pass header.i=@unidosnow.co header.s=default header.b=A8IkBXOE;
       spf=pass (google.com: domain of y2dg1g3q@cloud150.hostgator.com designates 192.185.145.170 as permitted sender) smtp.mailfrom=y2dg1g3q@cloud150.hostgator.com
Received: from cm14.websitewelcome.com (cm14.websitewelcome.com [100.42.49.7])
    by gateway32.websitewelcome.com (Postfix) with ESMTP id BA603208E2
    for <wjcaway@gmail.com>; Wed, 25 Mar 2020 18:45:08 -0500 (CDT)
Received: from cloud150.hostgator.com ([108.167.158.90])
    by cmsmtp with SMTP
    id HFhsjbetAXVkQHFhsjrhYK; Wed, 25 Mar 2020 18:45:08 -0500
X-Authority-Reason: ss=1
DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha256; q=dns/txt; c=relaxed/relaxed;
    d=unidosnow.co; s=default; h=Date:Message-Id:From:Subject:To:Sender:Reply-To:
    Cc:MIME-Version:Content-Type:Content-Transfer-Encoding:Content-ID:
    Content-Description:Resent-Date:Resent-From:Resent-Sender:Resent-To:Resent-Cc
    :Resent-Message-ID:In-Reply-To:References:List-Id:List-Help:List-Unsubscribe:
    List-Subscribe:List-Post:List-Owner:List-Archive;
    bh=M0VMoOovcbMGQ4upi/77pqMguHM5hO8iG91ARyXv/ho=; b=A8IkBXOER8wH9EqwIb2cZ6cM8T
    Joz6/OQ3eEE97kNVUxlMR1vwblgRskjcbN/0tk+7JCWnyydQsw09gDmc1tgudsYLIWOuNOiczpROA
    sawfsxhAidgo/O2odaQnqIBGSsfUlpTF+Q942j5lb0zU6ib0CrJqGEjM56hTcev2ENihq7x/GfFTC
    cpxcXTahPbHjR8Abbaa7FWySBbuikDjvwUaVQhAIsPQfFeqxAk8OI/+mumwtmdpzjjEV/s8N2XPuD
    6cTgxSQNhIHEuZ27ViqPTOeJ4PTyzIglsyMaucMHOxhCJq7mk4kFtV5oQ5FNc/Tx+zdKSl83KxpwI
    lTYp5l/Q==;
Received: from y2dg1g3q by cloud150.hostgator.com with local (Exim 4.92)
    (envelope-from <y2dg1g3q@cloud150.hostgator.com>)
    id 1jHFhs-000PWJ-Ju
    for wjcaway@gmail.com; Wed, 25 Mar 2020 18:45:08 -0500
To: wjcaway@gmail.com
Subject: An Email direct from the host!
X-PHP-Script:  for 
X-PHP-Originating-Script: 648:host_email_test.php
From: info@unidosnow.org
Message-Id: <E1jHFhs-000PWJ-Ju@cloud150.hostgator.com>
Date: Wed, 25 Mar 2020 18:45:08 -0500
X-AntiAbuse: This header was added to track abuse, please include it with any abuse report
X-AntiAbuse: Primary Hostname - cloud150.hostgator.com
X-AntiAbuse: Original Domain - gmail.com
X-AntiAbuse: Originator/Caller UID/GID - [648 501] / [47 12]
X-AntiAbuse: Sender Address Domain - cloud150.hostgator.com
X-BWhitelist: no
X-Source-IP: 
X-Source-L: No
X-Exim-ID: 1jHFhs-000PWJ-Ju
X-Source: 
X-Source-Args: 
X-Source-Dir: unidosnow.co:/cc-unidosnow-co
X-Source-Sender: 
X-Source-Auth: y2dg1g3q
X-Email-Count: 8
X-Source-Cap: eTJkZzFnM3E7eTJkZzFnM3E7Y2xvdWQxNTAuaG9zdGdhdG9yLmNvbQ==
X-Local-Domain: yes

From email: info@unidosnow.org
Comments: Test from php mail()
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to sign emails to setup DKIM and DMARC for all Drupal 8 mails](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/261192/how-to-sign-emails-to-setup-dkim-and-dmarc-for-all-drupal-8-mails)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is likely a HostGator-specific issue. Drupal sets Return-Path: from https://example.org/admin/config/system/site-information. Since our email domain is different from our hosting domain, HostGator refrained from producing a DKIM signature in the outgoing emails. I expected Drupal to set From: and/or Reply-To:, not Return-Path:. Bad expectations on my part.

Comment: Your expectations were fine. Drupal should not be setting "Return-Path", this is done by the receiving mail server.